# Android onNewIntent doesn't work when you click on push(oneSignal) when the app is closed

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, onesignal

I send a push with OneSignal, the additional data contains a link.
in the application, I open this link in the webview via onNewIntent. Everything works, but when the application is closed when you click on the push, the application opens but the link in the webview does not load. it feels like onNewIntent is being ignored. How to deal with this?

class application

```
OneSignal.setNotificationOpenedHandler { result ->
        result.notification.additionalData?.getString("url").let { url ->
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).also {
                it.putExtra("notification_url", url.toString())
                    .addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                    .addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    .addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
                    .addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
                startActivity(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

activity

```
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    intent?.extras?.getString("notification_url")?.let {
            myWebView.loadUrl(it)
    }
}
```

manifest

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

[problem on video](https://trud-udalenka.site/video_2021-02-24_21-56-32.mp4)

Comment: UPD: onNewIntent works. that does not work myWebView.loadUrl(it). Logcat: W/enonbrand.cati: Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (greylist, reflection, allowed)

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve the problem, but I'm already blundering hard.
Under this condition, everything works as it should. I don't know how to do it correctly in if. There must be something like this mWebView.isNotEmpty

```
if (???) {println ("mWebView.isNotEmpty")} else {println ("else") mWVmain ()}
```

how do I check the webview correctly (whether something is displayed in it or not)?